# Laravel merge relationship of multiple models into one query

Tags: laravel, vue.js, relationship

I would like to merge 2 relationships into one query from 2 different models

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{

public function relazioneFollower() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_follower','follower_id','following_id')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
}



class bacheca extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'id_post';

public function commento() {

    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'id_post_commento');
}
}
```

this piece of code works fine, but I would like to add the comment report, to be associated with the various posts:

```
$posts = User::find($current_id)->relazioneFollower()
    
    ->join('bachecas', function ($join2) use ($current_id) {
        $join2->on('following_id', '=', 'bachecas.id_utente')
        ->where('user_follower.stato',2)
        ->where('user_follower.follower_id', '=', $current_id);
        
    })
    
    ->where(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 1);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 2)
          ->where('relazione', 2)
          ->orWhere('relazione', 3);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 3)
          ->where('relazione', 3);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 5)
          ->where('relazione', 2)
          ->orWhere('relazione', 3)
          ->orWhere('relazione', 4);
    })

    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.cognome', 'users.fotoProfilo','bachecas.id_post','bachecas.title','bachecas.contenuto_post','bachecas.file','bachecas.immagine','bachecas.video','bachecas.audio','bachecas.posizione','bachecas.privacy','bachecas.created_at','bachecas.updated_at')
    
    ->get();
```

is there any way to merge the main query with this relationship?

```
$comment=bacheca::with('commento')->get();
```

or do you have a better way to merge these 2 relationships?

I would like to view the comments inside the posts always respecting the constraints of the relationship "relazioneFollower", thank you very much

Comment: but is there anyone? or are mine requests too difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the relationship between `User` and `bacheca`. Something like this may work, but you might need to change the foreign and/or local keys to suit your database schema:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

    public function relazioneFollower() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_follower', 'follower_id', 'following_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function bachecas() {
        return $this->hasMany(bacheca::class, 'following_id', 'id_utente');
    }
}
```

Then when retrieving the posts it should be as simple as using `with()`, but one caveat might be the `select()` method. I don't think you can grab the relationship fields from this method. Instead you need to add it to the `with()` method. Here's the full request:

```
$posts = User::with([
        'relazioneFollower',
        'bacheca.commento:id_post,title,contenuto_post,file,immagine,video,audio,posizione,privacy,created_at,updated_at',
    ])

    ->where('user_follower.stato', 2)
    ->where('user_follower.follower_id', '=', $current_id)
    ->where(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 1);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 2)
          ->where('relazione', 2)
          ->orWhere('relazione', 3);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 3)
          ->where('relazione', 3);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($filter)  {
        $filter->where('privacy', 5)
          ->where('relazione', 2)
          ->orWhere('relazione', 3)
          ->orWhere('relazione', 4);
    })

    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.cognome', 'users.fotoProfilo')
    
    ->get();
```